# Hide certain legend elements

Tags: legend, c3.js

I am using the names property to label a scatter chart legend. I have not been able to find a way to only show the legend for only data14, data15, data16 and data17 and hide the legend elements for data1 through data13.

data1 through data13 will always be the same, data14 through data17 could expand or collapse in number and the label text will change.

```
  names: { 
        data1: '2%',
        data2: '5%',
        data3: '10%',
        data4: '15%',
        data5: '20%',
        data6: '25%',
        data7: '30%',
        data8: '35%',
        data9: '40%',
        data10: '45%',
        data11: '50%',
        data12: '55%',
        data13: '60%',

        data14: 'Oracle',
        data15: 'HP',
        data16: 'MS',
        data17: 'Oracle'
   },
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your chart legend not visible:

```
legend: {
  show: false
}
```

Then, make the legend visible only with elements you want:

```
chart.legend.show(['data14', 'data15', 'data16', 'data17'])
```

Comment: Alternatively, we can hide certain legends in config -  legend: { hide: ['data1', 'data2' ... 'data13'] }, and do not call chart.legend.show after.

Comment: Using, legend:{ hide: ['data1',...]}, will work best for this case, it allows me to add to the last four data series, works great. I would like to get the       `legend: { show: false} chart.legend.show(['data14', 'data15', 'data16', 'data17'])` to work also in case I have other situations it would be more helpful. I placed the chart.legend.show right after the show: false, the chart does not show, do have have the syntax wrong or the location of the code wrong?

Comment: @user8038235 Where are you declaring `legend: { show: false}`?. Here you have an example: https://jsfiddle.net/L0weh3pf/